# Как сохранить значение инпута в локальную память?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

сейчас изучаю тайпскрипт и для обучения пишу тудушку на нем но столкнулся с проблемой сохранения туду в локальную память.. Я описал интерфейс Itodo но когда записываю todos в localStorage то по-понятным причинам мне выдает ошибку

> Argument of type 'Itodo[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Вот часть кода:

```js
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<Itodo[]>([]);
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  
  
  localStorage.setItem("todos", todos);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Как правильно решить такую ошибку и как потом сохранять тудушки в локальную память ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
```

Comment: Работает но почему-то при перезагрузке все данные с страницы исчезают но в сторедже хранятся

Comment: Потому что надо не только сохранять, но и вытаскивать.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Itodo[] это тип массива и тип Строка (string) к нему не подходит.
Поэкспериментируйте, вам же подсказка всплывает в программе как исправить

```
React.useState<Itodo[string]>([]);
```

Или

```
React.useState<Itodo[]>(string[]);
```